# Handling illegal XML values while reading emails with EWS

Tags: c#, xml, exchangewebservices

We have an application that uses a `StreamingSubscriptionConnection` to read *every* email that gets sent to a particular mailbox. The issue I'm running into several times a day during development I get the exception `{"'{square character}', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1."}`.

Here is the stack trace:

```
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Int32 pos, String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowInvalidChar(Int32 pos, Char invChar)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.Read()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.Read(XmlNodeType nodeType)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.InternalReadElement(XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String localName, XmlNodeType nodeType)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.ReadStartElement(XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String localName)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(EwsServiceXmlReader ewsXmlReader)
```

How can I safely read emails with EWS that contain illegal characters?

After much searching it appears it *was* possible to fix this issue with older versions of the EWS API. However, with the newest version of the managed API no one seems to have a fix.

This is a cross post from http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/22863099-1d93-47ac-a11b-08c6bf7facea .

I've managed to get the exception again and here is the full stacktrace and what Exchange is turning as a notification.

I'm using Exchange 2010 SP1.

[image: EWS Notification Exception]

Edit: I'm reviving this question, as it is causing me serious problems and the original question states the problem clearly. I am looking for client-side solutions that modify the behavior of the Managed EWS API to filter invalid characters from the XML and avoid exceptions. Exchange server fixes are unlikely to be an option, unless they are simple configuration changes. My software will be run against customer Exchange servers I do not control.

Comment: This post was answered on MSDN. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/9d1286f6-d02f-4924-9e37-9136eac06031

Comment: Henning: Do you mean http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/22863099-1d93-47ac-a11b-08c6bf7facea ? The link you posted does not contain a fix because we already have SP1.

Comment: As of 2014 this is still a problem with Managed API 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

A general workaround would be, to write a utility program that watches the inbox folder(s) as a background process, **if you can not solve the issue of receiving invalid XML files**:

That program would do the following:

- If a new file has been created and was written completely ([wait for close](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15251612/1500022)), open the file (exclusively), then search and replace each [non-valid XML character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) with it's [XML escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping): **&...;**

You should be able to safely replace all [non-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) characters below [US-ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) 32 with such an escape sequence, with the exception of '\r', '\n' and '\t'. However, you would also have to make sure that you never damage the XML files and that the changed XML files can still be used, by whatever system uses them.

Or look for one of the more common XML sanitizer libraries.