# Detect if there are new files created in a folder using FileWatcher

Tags: c#, file, directory, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to know if there are new files created in a given directory. I have next code:

```
private static void CreateWatcher()
    {
        //Create a new FileSystemWatcher.
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        //Set the filter to all files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";

        //Subscribe to the Created event.
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_FileCreated);

        //Set the path 
        watcher.Path = path;

        //Enable the FileSystemWatcher events.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private static void watcher_FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nuevo archivo creado -> " + e.Name);        
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWatcher();
        CreateFiles();
        Console.Read();
    }
```

In `CreatedFiles()` function, I'm creating on the path three new files (one zip and two txt). It detects two txt files but not the same with the zip file. How can I solve that?

Comment: My guess is that since `watcher` is a local in a method, it gets GCed and stops raising events. `Console.Read` might also block `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: it works fine in my side. Can you share the CreateFiles code? Maybe you are using a thread or something that is not writing down the file?

Comment: Now it show the tmp file. Why is doing that?

Comment: I've tried your code (creating the files from an external program) and it works correctly with a generic file as with the zip file, so it is probably caused by the code creating the files inside your project that has some problems with the Watcher.

Comment: What do you use to create the zip file? The Tmp file is usually created by the zipper application before creating the zip, if your zip application creates the file and then renames it the create file will not be performed on the zip file so you won't receive the message.

Comment: I'm using the library DoNetZip to create it

Comment: Show the creation function and also the notificationfilters!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using FileSystemWatcher to monitor a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017506/using-filesystemwatcher-to-monitor-a-directory)

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you take a look here.  This has been addressed previously.

[Using FileSystemWatcher to monitor a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017506/using-filesystemwatcher-to-monitor-a-directory)

Comment: Never put just links...give a detailed answer, remember the link can get broken..

Comment: If it was addressed previously, then the question should be marked as duplicated instead of receiving this kind of answers.