# Detect when a user opens a file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file

I am looking for something that detects when a user opens a file(much like anti-virus software), i've been looking, but all i could find is when a user creates/deletes/modifies a file **on a specific path**

Comment: I can't get much out of that :/

Comment: [`FileSystemWatcher` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher)?

Comment: @UweKeim OP is asking for something different. When a user opens a file.

Comment: @UweKeim I think FileSystemWatcher only triggers on changed, created, deleted, and renamed. I don't think it notifies on open/lock.

Answer (score -1):

You can use C# FileWatcher - Listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when a directory, or file in a directory, changes.

Example:
http://matijabozicevic.com/blog/csharp-net-development/csharp-monitor-directory-activity-using-fileSystemWatcher-class

[Using FileSystemWatcher to monitor a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017506/using-filesystemwatcher-to-monitor-a-directory)

MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher;

private void watch()
{
   watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
  watcher.Path = path;
  watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                     | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
  watcher.Filter = "*.*";
  watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
  watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
  //Copies file to another directory.
}
```

Comment: It has onchanged() oncreated() ondeleted() , but nothing for when a user opens a file?

Comment: NotifyFilters can help i think.. Lemme check..

Comment: with NotifyFilters.LastAccess we can detect file open event also.. Did you check?

Comment: No, do you have an easy example?

Comment: the snipped mentioned here is enough. You can add directly into your solution and check it..

Comment: I tried it, and it doesn't launch the event when i open a file in the given path( i tried C:\ and C:\windows)

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `FileSystemWatcher.Changed` event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed(v=vs.110).aspx

In order to detect when it is opened, you must set the `NotifyFilter` property to `NotifyFilters.LastAccess` (this will trigger the `Changed` event because the LastAccess property of the file is changed).

I've never used it to monitor an entire HDD, so YMMV.

Comment: Question is how to detect when a file is 'opened'.