# Check all downloaded files c#

Tags: c#, file, download, exe, antivirus

I am trying to create " a little antivirus" but i'm having trouble to understand how does the antivirus know what recent downloads are , for example avast starts analyzing an exe less than one second after i finish downloading it.
but how does it know that a file was downloaded? if there any way to have this comportement using c#? ( with any version of dot net )
if anyone is facing the same problem , found what i needed here :
[Using FileSystemWatcher to monitor a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017506/using-filesystemwatcher-to-monitor-a-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyword: [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

With this information provided, you should be able to experiment :)