# Look for file in folder, get & compare latest date created in c#

Tags: c#, directory, filesystemwatcher, datecreated

I need monitor a folder, see if a file or files has been uploaded. And then I need to get the created date & time of the latest file that has been uploaded and see whether the time creation of the file has been more than 30 minutes from the current time. I have used the FileSystemWatcher to monitor the folder but how should I proceed for finding and comparing the latest file with current time.

```
private void watch()
{
  FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
  watcher.Path = path;
  watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
  NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
  watcher.Filter = "*.*";
  watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
  watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

Private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
  //Copies file to another directory.
}
```

How shall I do that in c#. Please help!

Comment: look here for help on `FileSystemEventArgs` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But `OnChanged` fires once the file is created (uploaded) => the creation time will be `Now`. Do  you mean you want to check if the upload process took more than 30 minutes ? Or what exactly are you after ?

Comment: @user3185569 Actualy im planning to run the code as a scheduled task to be run every 1 hour. so im expecting it to then see if the latest file created in the folder has been created more than 30 mins from now.

Comment: Does the question with this answer not help?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15018082/868127

Comment: @claudekennilol yes but only partly. How do i check the latest file created in the folder and compare the time created to be more than 30mins from now.

Comment: @velvt a scheduled task has nothing to do with `FileSystemWatcher`. The watcher notifies you for any changes in the directory. If you have a scheduled task to run every 1 hour, you can just read the directory and check the files. No need for a Watcher.

Comment: cant you do something like `var halfHourAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30);
 var dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Temp");
 var fileList = new List<FileInfo>();
    foreach (var fl in dir.GetFiles("*.*"))
 {
  if (fl.CreationTime < halfHourAgo)
  {
  fileList.Add(fl);
  }
 }
 
 var selected = fileList.OrderBy(c=> c.CreationTime).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: I need to get only the oldest file in the directory (sort by created date) and compare this creation date if it is more than 30 mins from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, i can't really see why you need to use `FileSystemWatcher`. You say you have a scheduled task every 1 hour that needs to check a directory for creation time of files. So in that task, just do the below:

```
// Change @"C:\" to your upload directory
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\");

var oldestFile = files.OrderBy(path => File.GetCreationTime(path)).FirstOrDefault();
if (oldestFile != null)
{
    var oldestDate = File.GetCreationTime(oldestFile);

    if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(oldestDate).TotalMinutes > 30)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

To Filter specific files, use the overload :

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "*.pdf");
```

Comment: What if a need to filter a specific types of files, let say pdf?

Comment: Now if i need to access a directory that is not found locally on my computer but on a remote computer. Lets say @"\\testweb\checkfiles\"); But my computer doesnt have the permission to access that remote directory, i need to specify credentials of the authorised account user to do this. How should i proceed?

Comment: @velvt If it is accessible from the server you're executing the code on, go for it. If there are any further implications needed for network locations, then i think this is a different question - "How to access files in a network location using c#" and it is not directly related to this question "How to check from files created before 30 minutes ?".

Comment: I need to get only the oldest file in the directory (sort by created date) and compare this creation date if it is more than 30 mins from now.

Comment: When their is no file in the folder, it crashes with the following exception 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Value cannot be null.

Comment: @velvt C'mon! That's a simple if statement. Check the update.

Answer (score 1):

In the OnChanged event:

```
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        var file = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        var createdDateTime = file.CreationTime;
        var span = createdDateTime.Subtract(currentTime);

        if (span.Minutes > 30)
        {
            // your code
        }
    }
```

To filter on specific file extensions (such as pdf), you can use:

```
if (file.Extension == ".pdf")
{

}
```