# How can I watch a Filesystem watcher object filter for event changes ( watcher.NotifyFilter)

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

Is there any anyway I can watch a Filesystem watcher object filter for event changes ( watcher.NotifyFilter)

```
IF (watcher.NotifyFilter ==true ) 
( call this method )
else
()
```

and I want the IF/Else block to run evry 24 hours or schedule it as a service

```
DateTime lastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime("C:\\testfile.csv");

string Today_var = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Cscript_Activitylog.txt"))
{
    sw.Write( DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()+"\n\n");
    sw.Write("----------------------- Activity Feed begins - Test file change ---------------------------");
    sw.Write(lastModified.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"+"\n"));
    sw.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"+"\n"));

    Console.Write( DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()+"\n\n");
    Console.Write("----------------------- Activity Feed begins - Test file change ---------------------------");
    Console.Write(lastModified.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"+"\n"));
    Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"+"\n"));

    //if file was modified today manual script to check every 30 min
    // I intend to run this as  service to check this but I have not managed yet to run this 
    code on console yet to convert to a service script
    if(Today_var==lastModified.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
    {

        Console.WriteLine("------- -------------------##----There is a file update today ----");
     // set the time (In min in this case)
    System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30).TotalMilliseconds);
    t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(your_method);
    t.AutoReset = true;
    t.Enabled = true;
    }
    //Struggling with this part
    // How to do I check if filesystem watcher triggered any changes in the directory then 
    else if(fsw.Equals(true))
    {
        Process.Start("C:\\Do_this_file_Sync.bat"); 
        Console.WriteLine("File system watcher notifier event found");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
    else
    {
    Console.WriteLine("SLeeping 30000 - No file update today !");
    }
                Console.WriteLine("Finished Today {0}",DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
    sw.Close();             
}
```

I will appreciate any help coming my way to at least get this code completed for the Console application.

Comment: What do you mean by "event changes"?

Comment: Looks like this is related, if not a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017506/using-filesystemwatcher-to-monitor-a-directory

Comment: Please post the code that creates and initializes the `FileSystemWatcher` fsw.