# Periodically upload files dropped by client

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm looking for high level solutions for a client to be able to drop files into an FTP folder. I imagine I would check periodically if there are any files in directory and then perform the rest of processing.

What are some good solutions for uploading and periodically checking FTP folder Using AWS, .net C#

Comment: Write a service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have used the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) Class.  The Class Listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when a directory, or file in a directory, changes.

There are a few catcha's:

- The new file event can fire before the file is finished writing to the folder
- Multiple events can fire when the watched folder changes.

The code will have to run as a Service on a machine that has access to the folder.

Check out this item [Using FileSystemWatcher to monitor a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017506/using-filesystemwatcher-to-monitor-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Write a windows service that uploads however often you want it too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [Cloud Watch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Rule.html) that can be triggered every `x` minutes which could notify a SNS topic that a HTTP endpoint is subscribed to. The receiving controller could then do whatever checks you need and process any new files.