# SQL Server Integration Services - programmatically choose what files to import

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, filesystemwatcher, sql-server-2017

I'm not new to SQL Server but *am* new to Integration Services, so I want to understand if the following requirement is fully achievable in SSIS, or if I will need to consider some level of C# development to supplement:

We have 25 Azure VM's running Windows Server 2016 Datacenter - on each VM we have thousands of log files in different folders.  We need to have all these folders monitored and upon creation of any new file **with a certain string present in the name**, we want the contents of the file exported to a table in our Azure SQL Server 2017 database.

Is this kind of custom logic configurable in an SSIS project, or is SSIS more geared toward static definitions of file folders/filenames?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can implement a folder watcher within SSIS package. But you can achieve this in different ways:

**(1) - using a folder watcher**

You have to develop the SSIS packages you need to import data, then you must [develop a folder watcher using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017506/using-filesystemwatcher-to-monitor-a-directory) to read the changes in folder and if the file name meet the requirementes you should run [dtexec utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) (using shell) to run the relevant SSIS package.

**(2) - using SQL agent job**

You can configure an SQL server agent job to check the file changes periodically and run the SSIS package when required.

Comment: Hadi, thanks for the info.  Azure SQL Server unfortunately doesn't support SQL Agent, so that eliminates #2.  Regarding the other option - aside from folder monitoring, can SSIS be configured with custom filename requirements?  I see in your answer that you refer to it, but I can't tell if that is also something that would have to be written into the C# part.  I ask because if I can eliminate the folder monitor requirement, I wonder if SSIS could address the sole remaining requirement of picking up only files that have a certain kind of name.