# Low CPU-footprint Desktop "Listener"

Tags: c#, desktop-application, remote-server

My setup requires a web app to start a desktop app.  There is a method for doing this mentioned here:

https://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/How-to-run-a-desktop-application-from-a-web-page

However, I would prefer not to make a registry change.  Also, I have a file-system connection to the web server, so the server can write a file to my remote profile.

The question is, what is the best way for a desktop 'listener' program to detect that a file has arrived? (so that in this case it can run a script for a larger desktop program).

By 'best' I mean low impact, so preferably not checking the remote directory every half-second.  The environment is Citrix Windows, (code used is C#).

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using FileSystemWatcher to monitor a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017506/using-filesystemwatcher-to-monitor-a-directory)

Comment: Thank you, that looks promising.  From reading around it appears if `FileSystemWatcher` is only monitoring one (or few) directories its impact can be very low.  I am still wondering if there is a more direct trigger method, but I doubt I will improve on `FileSystemWatcher`.