# AWS EBS how to get file change notifications

Tags: kubernetes, aws-lambda, amazon-ebs

I am using kubernetes and using AWS EBS as a persistent volume.

Is there any way of detecting changes on the EBS volume such as a file update/add/delete?

It could be anything really, lambda to SNS or SQL, file system hooks etc?

Comment: You could hook up an application using a [FileWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017506/using-filesystemwatcher-to-monitor-a-directory) technology and have that trigger any service you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. It's kinda by design. EBS is treated as a block unlike S3 where objects are treated separately and offer object-level notifications.